# pandas: subtract row of column from another next row of another column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, math

I have a datetime columns on that basis I calculate `min_time` and `max_time`. so from current `min_time` of the row want to subtract from previous row `max_time` and want to save into another column. How to do that?

```
data = pd.DataFrame()
data['datetime'] = 18-6-22 8:22:22, 18-6-22 8:22:23, 18-6-22 8:22:24, 18-6-22 8:22:25, 18-6-22 8:22:26, 18-6-22 11:22:27
data['min_time'] = 18-6-22 8:22:22, 18-6-22 8:22:23, 18-6-22 8:22:24, 18-6-22 8:22:25, 18-6-22 8:22:26, 18-6-22 11:22:27
data['max_time'] = 18-6-22 8:22:22, 18-6-22 8:22:23, 18-6-22 8:22:24, 18-6-22 8:22:25, 18-6-22 8:22:26, 18-6-22 11:22:27
data['t_diff_time'] = 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 Day 3:00:1
```

Is there any function to do this?

**expected output :**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of [sub()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.sub.html) and [shift()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html). Of course, the first value will be null because for the first `min` there is no previous `max`. Try with:

```
df['diff'] = df['min_time'].sub(df['max_time'].shift(1))
```

Or, equally in result:

```
df['diff'] = df['min_time'] - df['max_time'].shift(1)
```

Returning:

```
           datetime            min_time            max_time            diff
0   18-6-22 8:22:22 2022-06-18 08:22:22 2022-06-18 08:22:22             NaT
1   18-6-22 8:22:23 2022-06-18 08:22:23 2022-06-18 08:22:23 0 days 00:00:01
2   18-6-22 8:22:24 2022-06-18 08:22:24 2022-06-18 08:22:24 0 days 00:00:01
3   18-6-22 8:22:25 2022-06-18 08:22:25 2022-06-18 08:22:25 0 days 00:00:01
4   18-6-22 8:22:26 2022-06-18 08:22:26 2022-06-18 08:22:26 0 days 00:00:01
5  18-6-22 11:22:27 2022-06-18 11:22:27 2022-06-18 11:22:27 0 days 03:00:01
```

Optionally, consider adding `fillna()` to exactly match your desired output:

```
data['diff'] = data['min_time'].sub(data['max_time'].shift(1)).fillna(pd.to_timedelta(0))
```

Outputs:

```
           datetime            min_time            max_time            diff
0   18-6-22 8:22:22 2022-06-18 08:22:22 2022-06-18 08:22:22 0 days 00:00:00
1   18-6-22 8:22:23 2022-06-18 08:22:23 2022-06-18 08:22:23 0 days 00:00:01
2   18-6-22 8:22:24 2022-06-18 08:22:24 2022-06-18 08:22:24 0 days 00:00:01
3   18-6-22 8:22:25 2022-06-18 08:22:25 2022-06-18 08:22:25 0 days 00:00:01
4   18-6-22 8:22:26 2022-06-18 08:22:26 2022-06-18 08:22:26 0 days 00:00:01
5  18-6-22 11:22:27 2022-06-18 11:22:27 2022-06-18 11:22:27 0 days 03:00:01
```

Comment: can you tell me how to use sub() and shift() together?

Comment: It's in the first line of code, I've edited my answer to include the hyperlink to the documentation. In essence `df['col'].sub(df['col_2'])` equals to `df['col'] - df['col_2']` with an additional fillna parameter option.

Comment: Thank you .. I got it. I thought you were talking about different logic.

Comment: Please check my last edit. I have added an additional comment to exactly match your deisred output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [shift()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) function. You can do something like this:

```
shifted_max = data["max_time"].shift(1)
data["t_diff_time"] = data["min_time"] - shifted_max
```